# Google API : Get the User name of a given Gmail ID

Tags: google-api

I have a requirement to get the user name of the person with given Gmail ID. Is there any Google API is available to do so? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This is not a absolute solution, but if you get a mail details using <Method: users.messages.get> from Gmail API by filtering "in:send" messages , Sometimes you get user name in this format {User-Name} <{email-id}> under "From" tag of the json response. But it is not certain to get user name followed by email-id. Sometimes it only gives email ID under "From" tag. I used this function below to extract user-name and email from the "From" tag:

```
def _get_email_and_name(self, email):
    temp = email.split("<")
    if (len(temp)) > 1:
        temp[1] = temp[1].replace(">", "")
        temp[0] = temp[0].rstrip()

        return temp
    else:
        return None, temp[0]
```

Answer (score -2):

[getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile) should do the trick. Gets you their email adress. ([alternate](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve-profile-information) for g+ api)

Comment: Hi Manmeet. I have Gmail IDs and I want to find out the name associated with it.
API which you shared is given following fields in output: "emailAddress",
"messagesTotal", "threadsTotal", "historyId".

Where I am not seeing any user name.

Comment: Hi, the second link provided does that. I provided two, I wasn't sure if you meant 'user's name' or 'username'

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. It was the User's Name I was talking about. I think Second link will help me. Thanks!

Is it paid service?

Comment: @haboutnnah the second link is broken, and you don't explain here nothing.